# LottieUWP embedded into Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp, lottie

I made a custom renderer for **LottieUWP**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(LottieView), typeof(LottieViewRenderer))]
namespace Gorilla.Forms.UWP.Source.Renderer.Lottie
{
public class LottieViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<LottieView, LottieAnimationView>
{
    private LottieAnimationView AnimationView;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<LottieView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null)
        {
            if (e.NewElement == null) return;

            AnimationView = new LottieAnimationView()
            {
                Name = e.NewElement.AnimationPath,
                FileName = e.NewElement.AnimationPath,
                AutoPlay = true,
                RepeatCount = -1
            };

            SetNativeControl(AnimationView);
        }
    }
}
}
```

And here is the `LottieView`

```
public class LottieView : View
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty AnimationPathProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: nameof(AnimationPath),
        returnType: typeof(string),
        declaringType: typeof(LottieView));

    public string AnimationPath
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(AnimationPathProperty);
        set => SetValue(AnimationPathProperty, value);
    }
}
```

This works, but sometimes when hovering or waiting some seconds, I get an error:

`WinRT information: Attempting to close a CanvasActiveLayer that is not top of the stack. The most recently created layer must be closed first.`

`at System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.IClosable.Close()
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.IClosableToIDisposableAdapter.Dispose()
   at LottieUWP.LottieDrawable.Draw(CanvasDevice device, BitmapCanvas bitmapCanvas, CompositionLayer compositionLayer, Rect bounds, Single scale, Byte alpha, Matrix3X3 matrix, Double width, Double height, CanvasDrawingSession canvasDrawingSession)
   at LottieUWP.LottieDrawable.CanvasControlOnDraw(ICanvasAnimatedControl canvasControl, CanvasAnimatedDrawEventArgs args)
   at Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.UnhandledError.Propagate()
   at Microsoft.AppCenter.Utils.ApplicationLifecycleHelper.<.ctor>b__17_1(Object sender, UnhandledErrorDetectedEventArgs eventArgs)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AppCenter.Utils.ApplicationLifecycleHelper.<.ctor>b__17_1(Object sender, UnhandledErrorDetectedEventArgs eventArgs)`

This seems to be a bug inside **LottieUWP** or is my implementation incorrect?

Comment: It might help to see your LottieView and the AnimationPath. I assume this is a json string? IOW, can you supply a MCVE (minimal, complete, verifiable example? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: From the error info, `CanvasActiveLayer` is not top of the stack, and it will be  released,  then it cause  the `canvasControl` parameter empty within  `CanvasControlOnDraw` method. So, you need check `LottieView` class and how you use it.

Comment: LottieView is my selfmade class and there is just a `Property` and a `BindableProperty` implemented